# Intuition behind this bayesian probability?

Tags: probability, bayesian

Original Question - Prevalence of a disease X is 0.1%. You take a test for this disease and it turns out positive. This test is 99% accurate. What is the probability of you having the disease given that the test is positive?

Answer - Using the Bayesian model, the posterior probability that we have the disease given that the test is positive is only 9%.

This makes sense to me.
However, if we change the accuracy of the test to 100%, the posterior probability that one has the disease given that the test is positive comes to a 100%. (Keeping the prevalence of the disease same)

Is there a way to intuitively understand how a 1 point increase in Test accuracy, results in the increase of posterior probability from 9% to 100%!

Comment: Think of an alternative test for that very disease that ALWAYS says you don't have it. Given that only 0.1% of the population has the disease, the accuracy of the test would be 99.9%! Of course, that test would be useless in real life, but it is useful illustrating how one must be careful when using accuracy to characterize testing methods for imbalanced problems.

Answer (score 1):

Let's think of population of 1000 people. According to the setting, there is only one sick person and 999 healthy people.

Let's assume the very likely case where the person who has the disease is identified as positive. The probability to have the disease given that the test is positive is  1/(1 + the number of healthy people).

If the test is 99% accurate, about 10 of the healthy people will be positive, and the probability will be about 1/11~9%. If the test is 100% percent accurate, no healthy person will be positive and the probability will be 1/1=100%.

Overall, we get that in this setting where the vast majority of the people are healthy, even a slight change in the accuracy of the test result in many false positives (healthy people identified as positives), and hence significantly affects the probability having the disease given that the test is positive.